# Sliding bottomsheet like redbus

Tags: panel, sliding, bottom-up

I want to implement a search feature similar to the redbus app. The screenshots are shown below. When I click on editbox, it should slide the sheet(from bottom) with the name of the cities as shown in screenshot2 and when I select any one of them, it should dismiss and fill the selected details in edit box. I have already tried working with [bottomsheet](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet), but could not find a way. Please help.

[image: Redbus Home Search screen]

[image: Search sheet]

Answer (score 1):

This is an angular material directive called bottom sheet:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/bottomSheet

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. But i figured out the way to do using the startactivityforresult(myIntent,1); I appreciate your answer though. It was informative , need more ppl like you rather than ppl who are just here for correcting grammar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
startactivityforresult(my intent,1) 
In your app. Let me know if you want any further help. Hope this helps u nuf.

Comment: Thank you so much @helperisback :) i was looking for the same.:)